# What is the consistency strength of negating Banach-Tarski paradox?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

What is the consistency strength of $\sf ZF + \neg BT$?

Where $\sf BT$ is short for [Banach-Tarski Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox).

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Asaf Say the theory is actually $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{DC}+\lnot\mathsf{BT}$, so we can develop Lebesgue measure without difficulties. Do we need an inaccessible to show its consistency?

Comment: @Andrés: That is what I expect to be the answer, but you could also ask about what sort of strength one gets in terms of fragments of the axiom of choice...

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, why DC needs to be invoked here?

Comment: @Zuhair: Without DC you cannot properly develop measure theory, since it is consistent with ZF that the reals are a countable union of countable sets, which in turn means that there is no non-trivial $\sigma$-additive measure on the reals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, does the statement of BT require DC for it to be meaningful? If not, then there is no need whatsoever to incorporate measure theory.