# Is Banach–Tarski paradox false without axiom of choice?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, paradoxes

I know that you need axiom of choice to prove Banach–Tarski paradox. But what happens with paradox when we remove axiom of choice? Does theorem become false? Or is there just no proof of it without axiom of choice?

Comment: It is never the case that a statement about a single, well-specified set, is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the last paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#Connection_with_earlier_work_and_the_role_of_the_axiom_of_choice), if you combine ZF set theory with the assumption that the axiom of choice is false, the Banach-Tarski paradox becomes undecidable rather than refutable. Indeed, ZF plus something weaker than AC called the ultrafilter lemma renders the BT a theorem; it doesn't need full ZFC. For more details, see [the 1991 paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm138/fm13813.pdf) that proved this.

As a result, the models of ZF in which AC is false, i.e. the models of ZF$\neg$C, include some in which BT follows because the ultrafilter lemma is true, but also some (such as the Solovay model) in which the BT is false. This is why the BT is undecidable in ZF$\neg$C. (These specific examples are owed to @Reveillark.)

Comment: It might be worth to add that, in the Solovay model, where all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable, the Banach-Tarski paradox is false. Indeed, ZF+DC, which holds in the Solovay model, suffices to construct the Lebesgue measure and prove that it is invariant under rotations and translations, which yields the desired conclusion.

Comment: Is there some proof that it becomes undecidable without AC?

Comment: @emptysamurai See clarification in edit.

Comment: @Reveillark Thanks; fixed.

Comment: I don't think it is known whether ZF+DC suffices.

Comment: (We sort of briefly talked about that in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3393327/462).)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thanks for your correcting edit. I think I may have misread Reveillark's discussion of DC in the Solovay model.

Answer (score 3):

Removing an axiom from a consistent system of axioms can't make a theorem false: if statement $\phi$ follows from a consistent system of axioms $\Gamma$ and for some statement $\gamma \in \Gamma$, $\lnot\phi$ follows from $\Gamma \setminus \{\gamma\}$, then $\lnot\phi$ follows from $\Gamma$, so $\Gamma$ is inconsistent.

[I'm not saying anything against J.G.'s very helpful answer. I am just trying to point out a general logical principle (which is actually confounded in some bizare logical systems, but not ZF and ZFC, so let's not go into that just now).]

Comment: This is actually a very helpful answer because mine assumes "removing" an axiom meant it's assumed false, whereas yours addresses another possible meaning - come to think, perhaps a more likely one to have been intended. +1.